# Procfile gunicorn custom module name

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn, foreman

**Context:**
I am writing a medium sized flask application (10-15 views), and in the process, I am hoping to organize the code in a manner that will make it easily maintainable and extensible (not a monolithic file as most Flask applications are).

The structure of the application mimics the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/) as follows:

```
/AwesomeHackings
    /ENV
    /AwesomeHackings
        /models
        /static
        /templates
        /__init__.py
        /awesome.py
        /awesome.cfg
    /Procfile
    /README.MD
    /requirements.txt
    /run.py
```

**Problem:**
I am unable to get foreman to work with a flask application which is not named 'app'. I would love to have run.py be the entry point to my application.

I am using gunicorn + gevent, and my current Procfile contains:

```
web: gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -k gevent app:run
```

I have been using `run.py` to test the application:

```
from AwesomeHackings import awesome
awesome.app.run(debug=True)
```

Thus I assumed I could simply substitute `run` for `app` in the Procfile, but when executing `foreman start` , gunicorn fails with  meaningless verbiage about modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution in [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/). The main parameter of gunicorn is module:

`gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE`

Where `APP_MODULE` is of the pattern `MODULE_NAME:VARIABLE_NAME`

While it seemed logical for the syntax to be a keyword argument app:someIdentifier, as all of the tutorials use a module named `app`, it is in fact not the case. The correct argument for my situation was `run:app`.

Comment: I have a very similar setup and although I understand why it would be run:app, it still doesn't work on my end. What is in your awesome.py file, exactly?

Comment: In this case, awesome.py contains the definition of the app object (and, back when I wrote simple monolithic flask apps, all of the views, etc).
From the directory which you run gunicorn, how would you import the 'app' object? I.E. from foo import app. That module,variable name combination is what needs to be passed to gunicorn. 
Can you provide more info and details about your setup? Happy to help over email (My username @gmail.com)

Comment: For anyone else's future reference. I fixed my problem and explain how in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921187/flask-and-gunicorn-multiple-modules-circular-imports-not-all-routes-accessib .