# Flask and gunicorn, multiple modules: circular imports - not all routes accessible

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

My problem is similar to [Flask and Gunicorn on Heroku import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206413/flask-and-gunicorn-on-heroku-import-error) and [Procfile gunicorn custom module name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670958/procfile-gunicorn-custom-module-name) but I can't seem to fix it using their solutions.

My Flask app has the following structure:

```
appname/
   run.py
   Procfile
   venv/
       ...
   appname/
       app.py
       views.py
```

run.py:

```
from appname import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "here"
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath appname app:app
```

views.py:

```
from appname import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/there')
def there():
    return "there"
```

Previously, I was experiencing erorrs when running `foreman start`, but those went away once I removed `import appname.views` from `app.py`.

**Now, `foreman start` runs the app and route `/` is accessible but `/there` is not. How come?**

Comment: why is the `/`-route not in the `views.py`?

Comment: @msvalkon it's separate while I'm trying to fix this problem, so I can prove that the routes in app.py are accessible and those in other modules not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooray! I've been able to have it work with the code I really wanted.

app structure (unchanged):

```
appname/
   run.py
   Procfile
   venv/
       ...
   appname/
       app.py
       views.py
```

run.py (unchanged):

```
from appname import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import appname.views
import appname.anothermodule
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn appname:app
```

views.py (unchanged):

```
from appname import app

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello, awesomeness!"
```

Comment: @neurosnap I'm not sure whether it does. When developing, I use run.py to start the app using `python run.py` though...

Comment: right because I don't actually point to run.py ever, which is why I was curious, I ended up fixing my issue thanks to your solution!  So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to move "around" this issue, by:

1. Not having `from appname import app` anywhere else other than in `run.py`
2. Consequently, only defining routes in `app.py`

I would have preferred to keep my routes with my modules, although I am unsure which is the better Python style.